# How can I sync game state dozens of times per second efficiently over the network?

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is [a fun school project](https://github.com/trevordixon/CS-455-Space-Duel) I'm working on. I'm using [Three.js](http://threejs.org/) to make a 3D [KSpaceDuel](http://games.kde.org/game.php?game=kspaceduel) clone, and [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/start) to hook up players and transfer game state. Here's the basic idea of what I've got right now:

```
conn = peer.connect(partner);

conn.on('open', function() {
    startGame();
    conn.send(game.getState());
});

conn.on('data', function handlePeerData(data) {
    game.updatePartnerState(data);
    conn.send(game.getState());
});
```

This tells each client to transfer game state back and forth to each other as quickly as they can each process a load and send back another. Here are the `getState` and `updatePartnerState` functions:

```
game: {
    getState: function() {
        var p = spaceship.mesh.position,
            v = spaceship.velocity,
            r = spaceship.mesh.rotation;

        return {
            position: {x: p.x, y: p.y, z: p.z},
            velocity: {x: v.x, y: v.y, z: v.z},
            rotation: {x: r.x, y: r.y, z: r.z}
        }
    },

    updatePartnerState: function(state) {
        with (state) {
            partner.mesh.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);
            partner.mesh.rotation.set(rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z);
            partner.velocity.set(velocity.x, velocity.y, velocity.z);
        }
    }    
}
```

This may not surprise some of you, but this makes for choppy animation and animation hiccups every 5 seconds or so—I assume it's the garbage collector having to kick in.

## Actual Questions

What can I do to efficiently transfer game state? Is JSON (de)serialization relatively expensive here? If so, what's a clever, cheaper way I can transfer all those numbers? If I avoid objects altogether as much as possible, will that put less pressure on the garbage collector?

Comment: If you really think the reason is GC, you should have a close look at your client code. Maybe this is of help: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/memory/effectivemanagement/